# How To Only Show Certain Number of numbers after decimal point Double Swift

Tags: swift, double, rounding

I am using doubles to log hours for my app. My problem is I only want to record the number and the first number after the decimal place otherwise sometimes the number becomes like this (x.9000000000001) and I only need the x.9.

I have tried rounding the double value but it still has this weird extra amount of zeros.

Any way to only get the double to show the first number after decimal place.

Thanks

Comment: Use a NumberFormatter when displaying numbers to a user so they output is properly displayed in a format appropriate to the user's locale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve rounding to the first decimal place is to simply do the following:

```
let x = 4.9000000001
let roundedX = Double(round(x * 10) / 10) // roundedX = 4.9
```

`roundedX` will be a `Double` representing `x` rounded to the first decimal. To get 2 decimal places, just multiply and divide by `100` instead of `10`.